# create a class for dynamic div based on mouse event

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a dynamic div using javascript. and here I want to assign the class name dynamically. like the below conditions.

1. on mouse hover set the class to `a`
2. on mouse click set the class to `b`
3. else set it to class `c`

my code is as below.

```js
var elementRange = document.getElementById("div");
 var elementSpan = document.createElement("span");
 if (elementSpan.onmouseover) {
    elementSpan.className = "a";
 } else if (elementSpan.onclick) {
   elementSpan.className = "b";
 } else {
   elementSpan.className = "c";
}
elementRange.appendChild(elementSpan);
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

here when I run this, the mouse hover/click is not working, only the default one is up. please let me know how can I do this.

Also, I use the only javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  For one, mouse click will *always* be preempted by mouse hover, and secondly these events can be identified by CSS pseudo-selectors, which I suspect would suit your needs better.

Comment: Also, have a read of this to help with the event handlers... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need bind EventListener at first also by `if else` statement not work for event as a event switcher how way you tried:

```
    var elementRange = document.getElementById("div");
    var elementSpan = document.createElement("span");
    elementSpan.addEventListener("click", function(){
        elementSpan.className = "a";
    });
    elementSpan.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        elementSpan.className = "b";
    });
    elementSpan.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
        elementSpan.className = "c";
    });
    elementSpan.innerHTML = "Lorem Ipsum"; //I added this line at least make span visible purpose
    elementRange.appendChild(elementSpan);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the methods in `Element.classList`

```
elementSpan.classList.add('a');
elementSpan.classList.remove('b');
elementSpan.classList.toggle('a');
```

more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

but as @Archer mentioned you are probably going at it the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

> here when I run this, the mouse hover/click is not working, only the default one is up.

Because you have not registered any events yet.

You have just created an element and checking immediately that they have any events registered.

This is not the way to set the class name. You have to listen to the event and do stuff in callback .For ex

```
elementSpan.addEventListener("click", function(){
    elementSpan.className = "b";
});
elementSpan.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
elementSpan.className = "a";
});
```

Or even you can use CSS pseudo selectors to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
elementSpan.innerHTML="Hello";
elementSpan.onmouseout=function()
                                        {
                        this.className="c";
                    }   
elementSpan.onmouseover=function()
                                        {
                      this.className="a";
                    }
elementSpan.onclick=function()
                                        {
                      this.className="b";
                    }
```

You may refer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q8sqqL4z/) for detail.